# On Gridview click show ViewFlipper android

Tags: android, android-gridview, viewflipper

I have a `Gridview` that displays images ..

On click of item (image) in `Gridview` , it should open `ViewFlipperActivity` , that is initialised with the image that was clicked .Which is not happening in my case

The `ViewFlipperActivity` opens with the first image that the `server link` contains

link used for GridViewAdapter http://www.blueprintstudiocollection.com/images/products/thumbs/

link used for ViewFlipperAdapter http://blueprintstudiocollection.com/images/products/large/

How do I pass the position of the item that was clicked in `Gridview`to Viewflipper .

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself ... Just passed the `position` value from `Gridview` itemclick to ViewPagerActivity ... and set viewPager.setCurrentItem(postion) after setting the adapter ...